# Put a comment in goals of "Run configurations" wizard in Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am writing a Java project using Eclipse, Maven.

In the "Run configurations" wizard of Eclipse I am running the following goals

```
-e clean install 
-e clean compile 
-e clean -Dtest=MyJUnitTest test
```

Since I am running these configurations quite frequently, instead of three configurations, I am thinking it will be more convenient to be able to write one.

```
-e clean compile // -Dtest=MyJUnitTest test
```

With //, I was hoping to tell Maven not to execute anything written after //. However, this does not seem to work and Maven complains about //. Is there any other delimiter used for commenting out in Maven? Is there are a facility of commenting out parts of maven command at command prompt at all?

Comment: Why do you need a comment there?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
call mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true % This is a comment %
```

Comment: Nope. Not working. I am getting " Unknown lifecycle phase "%". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase... " etc

Comment: Yeah, i thought i'd work because we do something similar with .bat files and this works in there. My bad.